# Patch file type value while updating data (Angular Reactive Form)

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I have  a reactive form where I have to add & update the data. Normal values are easily patched while updating, but in case of **file type value (image)** it **does not get patched in the input field**.

```
 this.form = this.fb.group({
      userId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      picture: ['']
    })
get userId() {
    return this.form.get("userId");
  }
get picture() {
    return this.form.get("picture");
  }
```

My API receives & gives back base64 version of the image. So,

While performing **add** operation, I'm converting the **image file into base64** & sending to API; in my database it is saved as **BLOB**.

```
uploadPic(files: any) { //convert file type to base64 while adding
    const file = files.files[0];
    if (!file) return;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      this.url = reader.result;
      var base64Index = this.url.indexOf(';base64,') + ';base64,'.length;
      var base64 = this.url.substring(base64Index);
      var raw = window.atob(base64);
      var rawLength = raw.length;
      let imgArray = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));
      for (let i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
        imgArray[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      this.imgArrayy = base64;
    }
  }
```

In case of **updating** the data, I'm converting the **base64 to file type** & patching it.

```
if (this.data) //patching values for update operation
    { 
    this.userId.patchValue(this.data.userId)
    this.picture.patchValue(this.dataURItoBlob(this.data.picture)) 
    }

dataURItoBlob(dataUrl:any) { // converting base64 to file type to patch
    const byteString = window.atob(dataUrl);
    const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    const int8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      int8Array[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    const blob = new Blob([int8Array], { type: 'image/*' });    
    this.holdBlob = blob;
    this.holdName = this.data.userId;
    this.holdFile = new File([blob], this.holdName, { type: 'image/*' });
    return this.holdFile;
 }
```

In the view

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="1 1 calc(25% - 10px)" fxFlex.lt-md="1 1 calc(25% - 10px)"fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" fxFlex.xs="100%" class="from-color">
            <mat-label class="label-padding">User Picture</mat-label>
            <ngx-mat-file-input type="file" formControlName="picture" placeholder="User Picture"
              (change)="uploadPic($event.target)">
            </ngx-mat-file-input>
            <mat-icon matSuffix>publish</mat-icon>
 </mat-form-field>
```

But it is not patched in the input field. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You cannot patch (set) a file type input for security reasons. Why would you want to in the first place..?

Comment: @MikeOne While updating the form, I must need the previous image to exist in the input section otherwise the user will not get proper information about the picture. And also, in every update operation we usually see all the input fields with its corresponding values.

Comment: The usual way of handling this is to simply show the image but to allow the user to delete it or upload a new one. For that scenario you don’t need to patch the file input (which won’t work anyway).

Comment: Well, if that is the case, then I'll need to introduce the preview of that image.
Thanks for you opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

i think to patch the value the syntax should be `this.form.patchValue({ userId: '<new_value>',  picture: '<new_value>'})`

Comment: generates error! I don't think, the patchValue syntax is an issue here :) thanks for your effort!